# Convert str with percents (url) to usual str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have strings like `C%2B%2B_name.zip` which are supposed as url encoded. How to convert them to `C++_name.zip`?
Py 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 3, you will need to use:

```
urllib.parse.unquote('C%2B%2B_name.zip')
```

See [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote).

Comment: Finally someone who read the question and provided a solution for Python 3.

Comment: for 2 -3 or 3-2 sometimes make confusion, many thing changes :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is URL library

```
import urllib
print urllib.unquote('C%2B%2B_name.zip')
```

and if you have names with other characters (not only English), then you can add `.decode('utf8')`